# Autohotkey - How to overwrite an existing hotkey, while remapping the original hotkey

Tags: macros, autohotkey, remapping

I want to do a seemingly simple action but I'm having trouble figuring out how. I want to remap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> -- which natively opens a 'find' window in the program I'm using -- but I want to create a new hotkey for the 'find' functionality, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. Here's my code:

```
^f::Send {Right}
^!f::Send {Ctrl down}f{Ctrl up}
```

The result is predictable. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> simulates the key presses for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, which then triggers my other mapping. In the end, both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> do the same thing.

How can I have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> inherit the original functionality of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (the 'find' window), while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> is remapped to <kbd>Arrow right</kbd>?

Comment: I figured out a way to do it in my case. Instead of attempting to map to the previous hotkey, I just map to a series of menu navigation options to achieve the same result.

Comment: I am trying to imagine why would one require such a weird remapping.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prepend a `$` to the first hotkey to prevent the `Send` command from triggering it:

```
$^f::send {right}
^!f::send ^f
```